# Rigorous, concise, self-contained, systematic presentation of calculus (real and complex analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book recommendation satisfying the above requirements, with the presentation accessible to graduate students. Ideally, it would develop real and complex analysis axiomatically, rigorously prove all the major theorems, make clear the logical dependencies, but avoid any unnecessary fluff. *Conciseness*, economy, logical precision and elegance of presentation are especially valued, i.e., not the regular calculus textbooks with 700+ pages, colorful exercises, real world applications, etc. Just the pure mathematics.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hardy, "A Course in Pure Mathematics."

Comment: I like Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis". It does _almost everything_ in less than $400$ pages, and it's built so you can skip chapters going in directions you don't need. But it's still a classical textbook.

Comment: I think Rudin has one of the best proofs of Cauchy's integral theorem. I have tried Bak and Newman, Priestley, Shilov, Garling, Flanigan, Alhfors, as well as Brown and Churchill, but none of them quite worked. Their proofs are either too complicated, too hand-waving or incomplete. Only Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* and Ash and Novinger's *Complex Variables* are able to prove Cauchy's theorem in a rigourous, crystal clear *and* efficient manner (and both of them adopt Dixon's 1971 proof, by the way). However, I believe that as a whole, Rudin's book is too dense for private study.

Comment: @JosefE.Greilhuber Is it possible that you meant Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, not his *Real and Complex Analysis*? The former fits the criteria above quite perfectly, while the latter is most certainly not self-contained (Rudin himself refers to Chs. 1-7 of *Principles* as required).

Comment: @mar_cel You're right, sorry for the delayed answer.

Comment: @JosefE.Greilhuber that's no problem. Thank you for your (slightly indirect) recommendation, it is the perfect answer to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to J. E. Greilhuber for the recommendation.